# Inclusion-exclusion formula and its alias names

Tags: math-history, inclusion-exclusion

I am reading *Probability* by A. N. Shiryaev.

1. One of the problems refers to "inclusion-exclusion formulas", also known as Poincaré’s formulas, Poincaré’s theorems, Poincaré’s identities.
2. One of my college textbooks refers to the formula as Jordan’s formula.

I can't find any material on the naming of the formula from Wikipedia or Wolfram.
My question is, do these two aliases truly exist?